# TAB does not auto-indent lines anymore

Tags: key-bindings, indentation, completion

I used to have a configuration for <kbd>TAB</kbd> which was doing something like this :

This is the code before hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

```
template<typename T>
class A
{

    }; // This is where I hit TAB
```

The code auto-indented as below after hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd>:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{

};
```

The <kbd>TAB</kbd> key used to work as above but now it does only auto-complete.

Can I fix this ? I can use <kbd>TAB</kbd> with <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> but it is hard to do always.

Here is my .emacs file

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/jdee-2.4.1/lisp")
(load "jde")

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d")
(require 'linum)
(global-linum-mode 1)

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-0.8.0")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
; care about this place
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "<tab>") nil)
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "TAB") nil)
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "<backtab>") 'yas-expand)
; care about this place
(setq ac-source-yasnippet nil)


(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/auto-complete-1.3.1")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(global-auto-complete-mode t) ; section1
(ac-set-trigger-key "TAB")
(ac-set-trigger-key "<tab>")

(defun my:ac-c-headers-init ()
  (require 'auto-complete-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-c-headers))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my:ac-c-headers-init)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my:ac-c-headers-init)

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/iedit")
(require 'iedit)
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c ;") 'iedit-mode)

(semantic-mode 1)
(defun my:add-semantic-to-autocomplete() 
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-semantic)
)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my:add-semantic-to-autocomplete)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ansi-color-names-vector ["#242424" "#e5786d" "#95e454" "#cae682" "#8ac6f2" "#333366" "#ccaa8f" "#f6f3e8"])
 '(cua-mode t nil (cua-base))
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (tango-dark)))
 '(font-use-system-font t)
 '(show-paren-mode t)
 '(uniquify-buffer-name-style (quote forward) nil (uniquify)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foundry "unknown" :slant normal :weight bold :height 113 :width normal)))))
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 2)
(setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)
```

**Edit** When I add JDE it fixed but now I cannot use auto-complete ? It doesn't complete anything.

Comment: Are you talking about using TAB to move to next field when inserting a yasnippet template?

Comment: Or are you asking how to use TAB for template insertion instead of auto completion?

Comment: second one, my TAB button is doing just complete things, I do not have any problem with yasnippet or auto-complete.

Comment: Bind TAB to one thing only, and should be used for auto-complete. It would be easier. You can bind RET to `newline-and-indent` for automatic indentation: `(global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)`. You can indent whole buffer or region (if selected) using the code snippet [here](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/03/27/indent-region-or-buffer/).

Comment: @TuDo Could you look at my edit, how can i enable y auto-complete for jde,it doesn't work when I coding java.

Comment: @VivianMaya Feel free to revert to your original question if I have misunderstood what you meant. I have reworded the question title and content.

Comment: This kind of thing happens to me sometimes, don't know why, just `M-x revert-buffer` and `TAB`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't have other packages bound to TAB, I think the behavior you want is provided by:

```
 (setq tab-always-indent 'complete)
```

With this setting the TAB key will first try to re-indent the current line. If the line is already indented properly it will call `completion-at-point` instead. You can customize the variable `completion-styles` to tune how the built-in completion behaves.

If you want to use the `auto-complete` package instead, you can hook ac in to `completion-at-point` so that it works with the setting above. This example configuration might be helpful:  https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/init-auto-complete.el

That example basically adds `auto-complete-at-point` to `completion-at-point-functions`, with a wrapper to handle some edge cases and a hook to wire things up when `auto-complete` is enabled.